# PyStan or PyMC3 to take advantage of machine learning desktop?

Tags: python, machine-learning, probabilistic-programming

If I want to take maximum advantage of the computing power of my 4 GPU machine learning desktop, should I use PyStan or PyMC3 for probabilistic programming in Python?

Comment: As far as I know, PyMC3 has weak-ish support for GPUs (PyMC4 is going to be better in that regard, as it's based on TensorFlow Probability). You may be able to get something working by messing with the Theano backend, but that's about it. PyStan, on the other hand, doesn't seem to allow GPUs - I haven't used it, but a quick search resulted in https://github.com/stan-dev/pystan/pull/625, which has been an open PR for a year now.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, GPU support for both is rather shoddy. Both are works in progress. I'd look elsewhere.

If you're really trying to create a performance optimized model, my recommendation would be to use [TensorFlow probability](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability) since it has first class GPU support and gives fairly fine-grained control over execution.

There's also [NumPyro](https://github.com/pyro-ppl/numpyro), which I haven't used personally but looks promising.